# How Can I Return the Executable's .java file path?

Tags: java, netbeans, path

I want to read a number of images which are on a folder called `images` at the same folder with my source code files. The path I use to read each image, is `..\images\imageX.jpg`. But it does not recognize it. I am using Netbeans.

Comment: Are the images in the `src` context or at the same level as the `src` context?

Comment: thanks @k_g :) in src file i have file.java and images folder, which contains all the images.

Comment: the error is that : javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the path to the `src/` directory in your web application:

```
String path = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

You can then append anything you need to navigate to your `images` directory.  So assuming that the `images` directory were located in a folder inside the `src` directory, the following should do the trick:

```
File imageFile = new File(path + "images/imageX.jpg");
```

Keep in mind that `getPath()` will return **with a trailing forward slash** at the end, so you don't need to include one when further resolving the path to your files.

Comment: in my code i am doing this: 
<code>File currentJavaFile1 = new File("."); 
      String currentCanonicalPath = currentJavaFile1.getCanonicalPath();
currentCanonicalPath=currentCanonicalPath+"\\src\\"+packageName+"\\images\\";  </code>

Comment: Is this a comment or a question?  In any case, you can't use the <code> tag when making a comment.  You have to use ` instead e.g. `Here is some code.`

Comment: oh ok sorry I'm new i didn't know. thanks :) so this is a code. I use it to create the path and  read the images. but I wanted to use something more "dynamical" that would give me straight the .java;s file path...is there any option?

Comment: can I have a full explanation of this? -> 'String path = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();'

Comment: The `path` variable I have defined in my answer should give you a path to the top level `src` directory where your Java code resides.

Comment: it actually returns me the path of the .class file but it can work that way too, i guess...